# How to call a specific function from a JS file from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension and i am trying to figure out how i can call a specific function from my `script.js` file from the `background.js` file.

So far, my background.js file looks like this

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
});
```

Which will run all the js from my `script.js` file when the user selects the extension icon.

However, i'd like script.js to contain two functions and when the user selects the extension icon, it toggles between each function.

For example, if my `script.js` file looks like

```
function makeChanges(){

 // some functinality

}


function undoChanges(){

  // some other functionality 

}
```

how would i specifically get one of the functions to run when the extension icon is clicked? Is this possible using `executeSript`?

Comment: I believe the execute script will run the file, but doesn't know about any functions you want called. To do that, just include the script file and call its functions as normal.

Comment: In the callback of executeScript run another executeScript with `code: 'foo()'` instead of file:

Answer (score 0):

Use popup...

So when user clicked to icon you can show any buttons for actions.

[chrome extension: browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call different functions in different cases - better make it with **sendMessage()**

After you loaded your **script.js** into current page with following **background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
});
```

You can send message to your injected **script.js** from **background.js**:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {'callFunction': 'makeChanges'});
    // OR
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {'callFunction': 'undoChanges'});
}
```

and inside your **script.js** add following logic:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{ 
    if(request.callFunction === 'makeChanges')
        makeChanges();
    else
        undoChanges();
});
```